# Sending ICMP ping

Tags: c, macos, ping, icmp, raw-sockets

For ICMP ping request (echo request) do I need to get the MAC address of the destination ? I am trying to learn how to implement this in C using raw sockets but can not understand how to get the MAC address of the destination.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: recommandation: get the source code of `coreutils` and have a look at `ping`. https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr:  `ping` is not in [coreutils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] do I need to get the MAC address of the destination ?

No you shouldn't, in most cases.

From the man-page of `raw(7)` (my emphasis):

> Raw sockets allow new IPv4 protocols to be implemented in user space.  A raw socket receives or sends the raw datagram **not including link level headers**.

This is only logical, because you might be `ping`-ing something not on the same subnet, in which case the MAC address would be the MAC address of the router.

To prove the point, [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part4/chap18/ping.c)'s some source code for an old BSD version of `ping` - first one I found on Google. Note that it doesn't attempt to find the destination MAC address.

Note that some UNIX `ping` programs do all sorts of fun stuff. Some versions for instance allow you to spoof the outgoing source IP. Some versions include `arping` functionality. In these cases they will be injecting things at a lower level (at the link level), in which case you will need raw headers.

Comment: I need to get the Mac address of the router which is the destination in this case (the next hop).

Comment: @Novak007,  you shouldn't need to do that unless you are *not* using raw sockets, but using raw ethernet packets. If you are using raw sockets then the OS will work this out for you.

Comment: As the answer suggests the ARP would take care of the destination MAC address. If you are using raw sockets and the OS will use the resolved address destination MAC for you ethernet header

Comment: It is different though if you want to create arp replies and responses in which case you would need to create an arp header.

Comment: @cmidi indeed. Normal `ping` does not do that, but `arping` (or a ping incorporating `arping`) will.